# Profit limit and loss limit in Binance Futures

Tags: c#, rest, binance, binance-api-client

I have a problem with the code in C#
I open a trade in Binance futures using Rest
with the correct code
But when I need to set profit and loss limits in that code, I have a problem
I need to set profit and loss limit at the same time in the code below
Thank you for your guidance

string apiKey = "XXXXXXXXX";
string secretKey = "XXXXXXX";

```
        // Set the API endpoint URL
        string apiUrl = "https://fapi.binance.com/fapi/v1/order";

        // Set the parameters for the order
        string symbol = "BTCUSDT";
        string side = "BUY";
        string type = "LIMIT";
        decimal price = 30000;
        decimal quantity = 0.001m;

        // Set the timestamp and signature for the request
        long timestamp = DateTimeOffset.Now.ToUnixTimeMilliseconds();
        string queryString = $"symbol={symbol}&side={side}&type={type}&timeInForce=GTC&quantity={quantity}&price={price}&timestamp={timestamp}";
        string signature = SignData(secretKey, queryString);

        // Create the request object
        var client = new RestClient(apiUrl);
        var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
        request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        request.AddHeader("X-MBX-APIKEY", apiKey);
        request.AddParameter("symbol", symbol);
        request.AddParameter("side", side);
        request.AddParameter("type", type);
        request.AddParameter("timeInForce", "GTC");
        request.AddParameter("quantity", quantity);
        request.AddParameter("price", price);
        request.AddParameter("timestamp", timestamp);
        request.AddParameter("signature", signature);

        // Execute the request and print the response
        IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
        richTextBox1.AppendText(response.Content);
```